# Proving an integral using parametrization and Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, parametrization, cauchy-integral-formula

Prove that $$\int_0^{\infty} {e^{-t^{2}}}\cos(t^2) \, dt = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$$

by integrating the function ${e^{-z^{2}}}$ in the counterclockwise direction around the boundary of the region {z : |z| $\leq$ R, 0 $\leq$ Arg z $\leq$ $\frac{\pi}{8}$ } and letting R $\to$ ${\infty}$

I believe I am supposed to parametrize this equation; perhaps ${e^{-t^{2}}}$ = ${e^{-(t+ib)^{2}}}$ and ${\cos(2bt-i\sin(2bt))dt}$ ?

Comment: For a given $R$ the boundary is made up of two line segments and a circular arc.  The parameterization of $z$ is different on each of them.

Comment: Hint: the integral along the arc vanishes as $R\to \infty$. For $\text {Arg}(z)=\pi/8$ use the substitution $z=t e^{i\pi/8}$.

Comment: The given integral equals
$$ \mathcal{I}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-z}\cos(z)}{\sqrt{z}}\,dz $$
and [since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\right)(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s}}$ and $\mathcal{L}\left(e^{-z}\cos(z)\right)(s) = \frac{s+1}{1+(s+1)^2}$, we have
$$ \mathcal{I}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s+1}{\sqrt{\pi s}(1+(s+1)^2)}\,ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2+1}{1+(u^2+1)^2}\,du. $$

Comment: The last integral can be evaluated through standard complex-analytic techniques. 
$1+(u^2+1)^2 $ vanishes at $\pm\sqrt{-1\pm i}$, i.e. at $2^{1/4}e^{(2k+1)\pi i/8}$, and by computing the residues of $\frac{u^2+1}{1+(u^2+1)^2}$ at the poles in the upper half-plane ($k=0,1$) one recovers
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\cos(x^2)\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$$
in a straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This proof DOES NOT use the *Cauchy Integration Formula*, neither Complex Analysis.

Let
$$
I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(1+a i)x^2}dx, \quad a\ge 0.
$$ 
We need to show that $\,\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Re}\, I(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$.

Squaring $I(a)$, and using the polar coordinates change of variables $dx\,dy=r\,dr d\vartheta$, we obtain
$$
\big(I(a)\big)^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(1+a i)(x^2+y^2)}dx\,dy=2\pi\int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(1+a i)r^2}r\,dr=\pi\int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(1+a i)t}dt=\frac{\pi}{1+ai},
$$
and hence,
$$
I(a)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1+ai}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\pi(1-ai)}{1+a^2}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}+1}{2}}-i\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}-1}{2}}\right),
$$
and therefore
$$
f(a)=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\cos (a x^2)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Re}\,I(a)=\pm
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{1+a^2}}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}+1}{2}}.
$$
Observe now that, since  $\mathrm{Re}\,I(a)$ is continuous in $a$ and does not vanish (since the real part of $I(a)$ does not vanish), for every $a$ real, then either we choose the plus sign, for all $a$, or the minus sign for all $a$. We choose the plus sign, since $I(0)>0$. Hence,
$$
f(1)=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\cos (x^2)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Re}\,I(1)=
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{1+1}}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+1}+1}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi(1+\sqrt{2}})}{4}.
$$
In general
$$
\int_0^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\cos (ax^2)\,dx =\sqrt{\frac{\pi\big(\sqrt{1+a^2}+1\big)}{8(1+a^2)}}, \quad
\int_0^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\sin (ax^2)\,dx =\sqrt{\frac{\pi\big(\sqrt{1+a^2}-1\big)}{8(1+a^2)}}.
$$